# Filling water animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-shapes

I am trying to get a wipe up animation to make a circle look like **it's filling with water**. I've run into two errors, and haven't been able to even tackle the 3rd one:

1. It fills up the wrong way
2. <strike>It resets to empty (black) after it has filled</strike> *
3. For now, I am using the `<img>` tags, but I would like to move this effect to `body { background-image: }` and need some direction on how to do this.

[What I have tried so far:](http://jsfiddle.net/um0rnL56/1/)

```css
#banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#banner div {
  position: absolute;
}
#banner div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: wipe 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: up;
  -webkit-mask-size: 300px 3000px;
  -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.25, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.27, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.80, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
@-webkit-keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vklf6kK.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uszeRpk.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Giving it a default mask position as [@anpsmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473016/anpsmn) suggested, doesn't reset it to black anymore.

Comment: Give a default mask position `-webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;` so that it resets to blue.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This can be achieved with a single div and a [`::before` pseudo element:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

- The `#banner` is given `border-radius: 50%` to create a circle and `overflow: hidden` to clip its children inside it
- The `::before` pseudo element is animated to 100% height and the animation is paused at 100% using [the `forwards` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode). It begins at the bottom with the use of `bottom: 0`
- The background images would be applied in place of the black and blue backgrounds on `#banner` and `#banner::before`

**Compatibility:** IE10+ and all modern browsers. The `-webkit-` prefixed property is most likely no longer necessary for your keyframe animations. [Check the browser compatibility chart over here on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

### Working Example

I have added the `cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4)` [which is explained in @ChrisSpittles answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740828/2930477). It provides a neat effect!

```css
#banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #04ACFF;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

</div>
```

Answer (score 130):

Here are four different versions to supplement [@misterManSam's brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/css-wipe-up-animation-to-look-like-filling-with-water/29739227#29739227).

## 1. With Easing

---

**Explanation**

If you filled up a circular bowl full of liquid, it would fill faster at the bottom and top than it would in the middle (because there is more area to cover in the wider middle section). So, with that crude explanation in mind, the animation needs to: start fast, slow in the middle, and then finish fast when the bowl narrows again at the top.

To do this we can use a CSS3 easing function: `cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4)`.

Have a look at the example below.

(*If you want to tweak the easing here is a great resource: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.2,.6,.8,.4*)

**Example:**

```css
#banner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #04ACFF;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

</div>
```

## 2. SVG Deliciousness

Let's take this one step further? What if we wanted to add a wavy surface on the "water" using CSS? We can do this using the amazing SVG. I created a wavy SVG image in Adobe Illustrator and then animated that to travel from left to right on a loop with a separate CSS animation and voila:

**Example**

```css
#banner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#banner .fill {
    animation-name: fillAction;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#banner #waveShape {
    animation-name: waveAction;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    width:300px;
    height: 150px;
    fill: #04ACFF;
}
@keyframes fillAction {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 150px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }
}
@keyframes waveAction {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-150px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
<div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
 c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
 c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

## 3. With pour line

---

This example includes a pour line (most bowls fill from the top, not the bottom). The pour line first animates from top to bottom while an `animation-delay` property prevents the fill animation from happening until the pour has finished.

```css
#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
}

#banner .fill {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

#banner .pour {
  width: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #009ae6;
  animation-name: pourAction;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes pourAction {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="pour"></div>
  <div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

## 4. With Serious Bling (with beautiful aesthetics)

---

This example adds a few more properties to the CSS to make it look a little more realistic.

```css
.bowl {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -20px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  margin: 20px;
}
.bowl:before {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -20px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, black 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, #000000 100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl:after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #039be4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.bowl .inner:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40%;
  top: 60%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .inner:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .fill {
  -webkit-animation-name: fillAction;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.bowl .waveShape {
  -webkit-animation-name: waveAction;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #039be4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
/* For aesthetics only ------------------------------------------*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 200 1.2em "Segoe UI Light", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  background: #039be4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
}
h1 strong {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Black";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.explanation {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  float: right;
  background: #e64a19;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.explanation p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bowl">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="fill">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
 c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
 c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Svg one is very nice! +1

Comment: Excelent work Mr. Chris! Thank you for sharing! I really love the simplicity achieved for the svg option. I would really want to have an accurate explanation to why the mask effect is achieved for the `path#waveShape` : why o why? :)

Comment: @j4v1 the `#waveShape` is masked by applying `overflow: hidden` to the outer container `#banner`. Have a look at this jsFiddle without `overflow: hidden` hopefully that will give you a better idea of what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/kqbbhsyf/

Comment: @ChrisSpittles This is fantastic. Great job! I've been trying to adapt it and make it larger, but I'm running into an issue with resizing. Is there a way to take this one step further and create some kind of a variable that controls the size of the bowl/water? If so, do you think you could post another codepen?

Comment: @JamesBarracca This uses SASS to set the size:
http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/KWvPjG?editors=0100
Change the `$width` variable to suit your needs.

Comment: Excellent solution mr. Chris!!! I'm currently trying to use your n.2 solution, but I need to fill just a certain percentage of the circle. Do you have any advice how to achieve that? I'm not an svg expert. Thanx anyway :)

Comment: @kamakatekki, You can halve the 100% translation value: `@keyframes fillAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 150px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, 75px);
        }
    }` or simply swap the values to percentages.

Answer (score 10):

Pure CSS, no JavaScript, no SVG. Switch `overflow: hidden` off in `.shape`  to see how simple it works.

Made it using [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). You can fined **fill-up** and **animate** `@keyframes`

If you wish to use JavaScript for loading filling - you can access `.wave` element. The `top: 50%;` is 0% and `top: -75%` is 100% of loading. You can play with this digits as you want.

```css
.shape {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: translate(-25%, 0);
  background: #4973ff;
  animation: fill-up 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes fill-up {
  to {
    top: -75%;
  }
}

.wave:before,
.wave:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
  background: #000;
}

.wave:before {
  border-radius: 45%;
  background: rgba(179, 241, 255, 1);
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}

.wave:after {
  border-radius: 40%;
  background: rgba(179, 241, 255, 0.5);
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="wave">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this accomplishes your first goal:

```
#banner div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: wipe 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: up;
  -webkit-mask-size: 300px 3000px;
  -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top,
    color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    color-stop(0.25,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    color-stop(0.27,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    color-stop(0.80,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)));
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes wipe {
     0% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  }
     100% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00BFFF;  
  -webkit-animation: animtop 5s forwards, animtop2 2s forwards;
  animation: animtop 5s forwards, animtop2 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animtop{  
  0%{top: 100%;}  
  75%{top: 0}
}
@keyframes animtop{  
  0%{top: 100%;}  
  100%{top: 25%}
}
@-webkit-keyframes animtop2{  
  75%{top: 25%;}  
  100%{top: 0}
}
@keyframes animtop2{  
  75%{top: 25%;}  
  100%{top: 0}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the working working codpen of Water filling in a div on Hover

**HTML**

```
<div class="dot">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dot {
  border: 1px;  
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to top, #76daff 50%, transparent 50%);
  transition: background-position 3000ms, color 3000ms ease, border-color 3000ms ease;
}

.dot:hover {
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to top, #76daff 51%, transparent 50%);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 3000ms, color 3000ms ease, border-color 3000ms ease;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ajitkumar96/pen/pOYbQm?editors=1100