# Creating custom graphics which can be filled with color using html, css

Tags: css, canvas, svg, css-animations, css-shapes

[image: **enter image description here**]

This custom graphic need to fill with three different colors. Every color will be filled with 1-100%. So blue color will be filled from leg to head ( 1-100% ), red color will be filled from bottom of the head to top of the head ( 1-100% ) and so the orange color. Can this possible using svg / canvas or any other way?

Comment: show what you have done

Comment: In SVG you can create 3 shapes and 3 colored rectangles and apply clipping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS animation method**

1. Segment the three different color sections with different divs. Position it in the HTML according to the priority or give it `z-index` regardless of the markup.
2. Sub divide the color sections for creating the holder and filling up background. Although this can be created with `:before` and `:after` I have used nested divs.
3. Create a fill-up key frame animation which transitions from 0% height to 100% height. More info about the filling up animation can be found in these answers: [CSS Wipe up animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/css-wipe-up-animation-to-look-like-filling-with-water)
4. The `animation-delay` needs to be calculated before, according to the number of shapes you have. If the first shape has a animation duration of 2s, give the next shape animation-delay of 2s which creates a sequential effect.

Manipulate the border-radius, position, width and height values to get the desired shape and position.

*Edit: Updated with a status indicator in Codepen*

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/ManojAMK/pen/qOZQZX/)

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}

/* Red Filler */

.red-filler {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.red-liquid {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: fill-up 6s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  background: #E63B44;
}

/* Orange Filler */

.orange {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
.orange-filler-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.orange-liquid-1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
  animation: fill-up 3s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-delay: 3s;
  background: #EC952E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.orange-filler-2 {
  background: lightgray none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
  border-color: white;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: none solid solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -74px;
  width: 100px;
}
.orange-liquid-2 {
  animation: fill-up 3s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  background: #EC952E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Blue Filler */

.blue {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
.blue-filler-1 {
  background: lightgray none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  left: -20px;
  top: -10px;
}
.blue-liquid-1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
  animation: fill-up 2s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-delay: 4s;
  background: #566EB1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blue-filler-2 {
  background: lightgray none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 275px;
  left: -25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 275px;
}
.blue-liquid-2 {
  animation: fill-up 2s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  background: #566EB1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.blue-filler-3 {
  background: lightgray none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  height: 110px;
  left: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -125px;
  width: 150px;
}
.blue-liquid-3 {
  animation: fill-up 2s ease forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  background: #566EB1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Container for centering */

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
/* Animation Keyframe */

@keyframes fill-up {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Red container -->
  <div class="red">
    <div class="red-filler">
      <div class="red-liquid"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Orange container -->
  <div class="orange">
    <div class="orange-filler-1">
      <div class="orange-liquid-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="orange-filler-2">
      <div class="orange-liquid-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Blue container -->
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="blue-filler-1">
      <div class="blue-liquid-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue-filler-2">
      <div class="blue-liquid-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue-filler-3">
      <div class="blue-liquid-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You just made my day :)
Solved my problem very easily, thanks a ton Manoj. Keep it up.

Comment: And your comment made my day. Thanks for the appreciation! :)