# SVG water fill animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, fill

I am to get a wipe animation to look like water is filling up inside of a drop. It currently is a square with a wave animation over top of the drop logo. It does the wave animation correctly but I can't get it to stay inside the drop and also fill up.

I'm getting closer but I still need the actual logo to be inside the circle at least.

My progress:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>SVG Line Animation Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>

    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:5;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:5;}

    #logo2 {
        width: 150px !important;
        height: 150px !important;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

    #banner {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-bottom: -50px;
    }

    #banner .fill {
        animation-name: fillAction;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    #banner #waveShape {
        animation-name: waveAction;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        width:300px;
        height: 150px;
        fill: #04ACFF;
    }

    @keyframes fillAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 150px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, -5px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes waveAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-150px, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
    }

</style>

<div>
    <div id="banner">
        <div class="fill">

            <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 136 195" style="enable-background:new 0 0 136 195;" xml:space="preserve">

                <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
            </svg>
         </div>
    </div>        

    <svg version="1.1" id="logo2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 136 195" style="enable-background:new 0 0 136 195;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z"/>
        <g><path class="st1" d="M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z"/></g>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The wave is entirely above the drop, if I clip the wave to the drop then the drop will simply appear to be full all the time as it rises. Please explain more clearly what you want to see here.

Comment: Basically I want the animation to fill the entire drop. As seen in the "SVG Deliciousness" section on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/filling-water-animation/29740828#_=_

Comment: You just want a blue drop that moves upwards then with no wave effect?

Comment: I don't want the drop logo to move I just want the water animation to fill up the drop.

Answer (score 20):

The following modifies your code to:

- remove the viewport (I just find it easier to use `transform`),
- make a copy of both the drop and the "h" letter,
- merge the copies into a single path,
- place that merged path inside a `<clipPath>` element inside a `<defs>` element in the `<svg>` and give it an id ("drop")
- place an enclosing `<g>` element around the `<g class="fill">` group,
- clip that enclosing `<g>` element using the "drop", and
- scale and translate both the black-bordered drop-and-h as well as the clip path drop-and-h by the same amounts so that they are centered on the waveshape.

You can read about [clipPath on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath).

By the way, note that your wave shape animation may continue forever even if you can't see the waves sloshing around any more (though I didn't check this rigorously), which is probably not what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>SVG Line Animation Demo</title>

</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 4;
      stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    }
    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    }
    #logo2 {
      width: 150px !important;
      height: 150px !important;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -100px;
    }
    #banner {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background: #fff;
      overflow: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      z-index: -1;
      margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
    #banner .fill {
      animation-name: fillAction;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #banner #waveShape {
      animation-name: waveAction;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      fill: #04ACFF;
    }
    @keyframes fillAction {
      0% {
        transform: translate(0, 150px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
      }
    }
    @keyframes waveAction {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-150px, 0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
      }
    }
  </style>


  <div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div>
        <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
            <clipPath id="drop">
              <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
            </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
            <g class="fill">
              <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
            <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />
            <path class="st1" d="M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am forever in your debt. Thank you.

Comment: How did you make the wave so smooth? Mine is choppy

Comment: The wave had nothing to do with my efforts...it was constructed by the OP. Re-ask your question as a comment on the original question and she/he'll perhaps give you some insight!