# How to add background colors to pattern fills?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

How do I convert this code so that the path with id `#wires` has the color `#000` initially and then being colored by the pattern and keyframes as oppossed to no color at all? So essentially the star should be black and the gradient animation will creep up the star. How do I achieve this?

This was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/42032657/5586359.

```css
.fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.26, .64, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#wires {
  fill: url(#waveGradient);
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -1.6%);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-0%, 0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-5%, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10%, 0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-20%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-10%, 0);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(-5%, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <!-- Generator: Gravit.io -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 250 250" width="250" height="250">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="_clipPath_kDqJpeywA1tWpdDxczhcHinYaTsaw8EY"><rect width="250" height="250"/>
      </clipPath>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#333291"/>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="purple"/>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fb5b5d" stop-opacity="100" />
      </linearGradient>
      <pattern id='waveGradient' width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g class="fill">
          <path fill="url(#gradient)" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
                                                  c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
        </g>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_kDqJpeywA1tWpdDxczhcHinYaTsaw8EY)">
      <path id="wires" d="M12.015.624L9.19 9.293H0l7.445 5.384-2.819 8.673L12 17.986l7.422 5.393-2.835-8.713L24 9.292h-9.162L12.015.622v.002z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to duplicate the path of the star and you fill it with the color you want. Both will be placed above each other and you will have the visual you want

```css
.fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.26, .64, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#wires {
  fill: url(#waveGradient);
}
#empty {
  fill:#000;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -1.6%);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-0%, 0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-5%, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10%, 0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-20%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-10%, 0);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(-5%, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 250 250" width="250" height="250">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#333291"/>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="purple"/>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fb5b5d" stop-opacity="100" />
      </linearGradient>
      <pattern id='waveGradient' width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g class="fill">
          <path fill="url(#gradient)" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
                                                  c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
        </g>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g >
      <path id="empty" d="M12.015.624L9.19 9.293H0l7.445 5.384-2.819 8.673L12 17.986l7.422 5.393-2.835-8.713L24 9.292h-9.162L12.015.622v.002z"/>
      <path id="wires" d="M12.015.624L9.19 9.293H0l7.445 5.384-2.819 8.673L12 17.986l7.422 5.393-2.835-8.713L24 9.292h-9.162L12.015.622v.002z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson hmm .. true, I still forget to test on FF when it comes to SVG. By the way even the OP code is not animating ... I guess you know why? :)