# How to stack and animate 2 svg paths?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'd like to animate my logo by filling circle with water and moving my logo inside the circle. I have 2 separate svg paths. One of water and second of my logo.
When I try to animate them by putting in div #banner I get both animated but logo is 'out of view'. I tried adding z index but it didn't help.
Here's my code:

```css
 .logo{z-index:1000;
    position: relative;}
    
    #banner {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #b7c6ce;
        overflow: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #banner .fill {
        animation-name: fillAction;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #banner #waveShape {
        animation-name: waveAction;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        width:300px;
        height: 150px;
        fill: #04ACFF;
        z-index:-1;
    }
    
    @keyframes fillAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 150px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, -5px);
        }
    }
    @keyframes waveAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-150px, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div id="banner">
        <div class="fill">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
              <path fill="none" class="logo" viewBox="0 0 150 150" style="width:150px;height:150px;" stroke="#047F63" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M200.922,388.703c-6.49,3.878-13.178,6.828-20.265,9.046
          c-11.806,3.683-22.87,5.527-33.191,5.527c-17.342,0-33.564-3.592-48.683-10.784c-15.128-7.188-28.309-16.69-39.554-28.488
          c-11.254-11.812-20.103-25.363-26.556-40.662c-6.452-15.31-9.678-31.074-9.678-47.296c0-18.813,3.128-35.877,9.403-51.173
          c6.267-15.31,15.122-28.49,26.557-39.551c11.427-11.065,24.98-19.558,40.658-25.451c15.673-5.898,32.727-8.85,51.174-8.85
          c18.435,0,33.465,2.858,45.082,8.572c11.617,5.715,20.832,12.353,27.664,19.918c6.816,7.552,11.798,15.113,14.931,22.684
          c0.735,1.773,1.318,3.098,1.942,4.68l0.313,0.078c6.515-3.902,12.951-6.769,20.064-8.994c11.809-3.684,22.875-5.534,33.194-5.534
          c17.343,0,33.566,3.596,48.681,10.788c15.127,7.196,28.308,16.695,39.559,28.491c11.251,11.806,20.104,25.36,26.555,40.66
          c6.454,15.31,9.678,31.073,9.678,47.298c0,18.811-3.129,35.874-9.402,51.17c-6.268,15.309-15.119,28.489-26.559,39.555
          c-11.424,11.065-24.974,19.553-40.658,25.449c-15.67,5.896-32.724,8.848-51.172,8.848c-18.436,0-33.469-2.861-45.084-8.572
          c-11.617-5.711-20.832-12.351-27.663-19.914c-6.816-7.561-11.798-15.12-14.932-22.683
          C402.155,391.527,400.922,388.703,400.922,388.7V300H300z"/>
              <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
          c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
          c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I took code from [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/filling-water-animation/29740828#*=*][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/filling-water-animation/29740828#_=_][1])

[1]: http://wateranimation tried to edit but no luck so far.
Many thanks in advance for help,
Neko

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but I can't find anything that uses the logo class in your example

Comment: Hi Dale Ill correct that. I mustve edited another version.

Comment: @Dale_dale12 unfortunately still no luck after adding class. Is it possible to put one svg image on top of another but animate them differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The logo is first in the SVG file, so it is hidden behind the blue water.  You need to move it so it is after the water path.
2. The logo is too large relative to everything else, so you need to scale and move it a bit so it is in the right place and is the right size.  To do that, I added a transform to the logo path:

   ```
   transform="scale(0.3,0.3) translate(30,-30)"
   ```

With those changes, you get a better result.

```css
.logo{z-index:1000;
    position: relative;}
    
    #banner {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #b7c6ce;
        overflow: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    #banner .fill {
        animation-name: fillAction;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #banner #waveShape {
        animation-name: waveAction;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        width:300px;
        height: 150px;
        fill: #04ACFF;
        z-index:-1;
    }
    
    @keyframes fillAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 150px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, -5px);
        }
    }
    @keyframes waveAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-150px, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="fill">
    <svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" overflow="visible">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
          c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
          c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
      <path transform="scale(0.3,0.3) translate(30,-30)"
            fill="none" class="logo" stroke="#047F63" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M200.922,388.703c-6.49,3.878-13.178,6.828-20.265,9.046
          c-11.806,3.683-22.87,5.527-33.191,5.527c-17.342,0-33.564-3.592-48.683-10.784c-15.128-7.188-28.309-16.69-39.554-28.488
          c-11.254-11.812-20.103-25.363-26.556-40.662c-6.452-15.31-9.678-31.074-9.678-47.296c0-18.813,3.128-35.877,9.403-51.173
          c6.267-15.31,15.122-28.49,26.557-39.551c11.427-11.065,24.98-19.558,40.658-25.451c15.673-5.898,32.727-8.85,51.174-8.85
          c18.435,0,33.465,2.858,45.082,8.572c11.617,5.715,20.832,12.353,27.664,19.918c6.816,7.552,11.798,15.113,14.931,22.684
          c0.735,1.773,1.318,3.098,1.942,4.68l0.313,0.078c6.515-3.902,12.951-6.769,20.064-8.994c11.809-3.684,22.875-5.534,33.194-5.534
          c17.343,0,33.566,3.596,48.681,10.788c15.127,7.196,28.308,16.695,39.559,28.491c11.251,11.806,20.104,25.36,26.555,40.66
          c6.454,15.31,9.678,31.073,9.678,47.298c0,18.811-3.129,35.874-9.402,51.17c-6.268,15.309-15.119,28.489-26.559,39.555
          c-11.424,11.065-24.974,19.553-40.658,25.449c-15.67,5.896-32.724,8.848-51.172,8.848c-18.436,0-33.469-2.861-45.084-8.572
          c-11.617-5.711-20.832-12.351-27.663-19.914c-6.816-7.561-11.798-15.12-14.932-22.683
          C402.155,391.527,400.922,388.703,400.922,388.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul LeBeau I've edited it a bit and here's final result [link](http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/water_animation5.html)