# Liquid filling text with animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a CSS animation to make a text like it's filling with liquid. I've followed an example ([Filling water animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/filling-water-animation/29740828)) but what I need is doing the same with a text, not a circle.

[image: Something like this effect]

Can I do it only using CSS? I don't need to correlate percentaje text with how much does the text fills. I mean, if I write 73% I don't need to automatically fill until 73% capacity.

```css
#banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff0019;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 73%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">73%</div>
```

Comment: I think this is probably more of what you were looking for:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738787/filling-water-animation/29740828#answer-29740828  the svg one

Comment: Might have to combine it with knockout text: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is text that fills like liquid.
Works great in Chrome but needs tweaking in Firefox.

```css
#banner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 40pt;
font-weight: bold;
background: #ccc
}
.inner {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
 }
#banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #0f0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 73%;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="banner">
    <span class="inner">73%</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This solution it's perfect for me!!! I'll try to fix it for Firefox (and see how it works in Explorer) but thank you for this.